# Receiving SMS from Twilio sent with test credentials?

Tags: sms, twilio

I sent SMS using Twilio test credentials (https://www.twilio.com/console/project/settings) as described here (https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/test-credentials#test-sms-messages).

Is there any possibility to view SMS body?
Or are there any other possibilities to receive SMS from Twilio not spending money (near 0.09$ to my Country)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send an actual SMS, then you are charged for sending the SMS. The test credentials are more for exercising the API. You cannot view the message log using the test credentials, ("message": "Resource not accessible with Test Account Credentials").

[How To Use Twilio Test Credentials with Magic Phone Numbers](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/04/twilio-test-credentials-magic-numbers.html)